# Activemq+Spring+Weblogic XA transaction

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I am working on one requirement using Spring boot with Activemq.I am using XA transaction and using application server is weblogic.
I have created durable subscriber using subscriber name and client-id.Now the question is I am not able to rollback the message back to topic in case of exception.
I tried with queue and it is working fine in case of rollback(automatic message send to DLQ in case of failure) but for topic it is not rollbacking.
I am seeing in active durable subscriber is 1-Enqueued message and 1-Dequeued message.It suppose to 1-Enqueued and 0-Dequeued.